# MPMovieplayer customising with Overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I want to customize my MPMoviePlayer with custom buttons overlaid on it.
Is there any tutorial/source code for MPMoviePlayer overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MPMoviePlayerViewController and hide the default controls, then, you can add any customized views to the view of controller.